# Select options won't display when parent div is shown after being hidden

Tags: jquery, css, select, hide, show

I have a select box that is nested inside three divs as such:

```
<div id="entry">
    <div id="entryContent">           
         <div>
              <div>
                   Name:
                   <select name="ddlName" id="ddlName">
                    <option value="Name1">Name1</option>
                    <option value="Name2">Name2</option>
                    <option value="Name3">Name3</option>
                   </select>
              </div>
              ...
         </div>
         ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#entry
{
    position:absolute;
    width:527px;
    height:364px;
    left:69px;
    top:214px;
    z-index:2;
    display:none;
}
```

The following jquery code is to show/hide the entry div based on clicking certain buttons:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#addButton").live("click", function(event) {
        $("#entry").show();
    })
    $("#closeEntry").live("click", function(event) {
        $("#entry").hide();
    })
})
```

The problem is that when I first click the add button, it shows the entry div and the select box works fine. After I click the close button and click the add button again, the select box will not let me select another option. It works fine in firefox but not ie7.

Comment: If you can post this on jsfiddle or jsbin it's cool.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in IE7...

Comment: @bleeeah Maybe you meant this: http://jsfiddle.net/FtCn5/1/

Comment: Works in IE8compat, can't reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

Found that it has something to do with jQuery UI CSS file. When I exclude it, the works. When I added an effect to the hide() and show() function, then it worked properly.